# How to use theme colors for "color" prop used in MaterialUI components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to use the colors from my Mui pallete as values for `color` prop like so:

Example:

```
  <Tabs
    indicatorColor="primary.mainGradient"
  >
    <Tab />
  </Tabs>
```

But that doesnt work, Ive also tried using `useTheme` like so:

```
indicatorColor={theme.palette.primary.mainGradient}
```

That didn't work either. How can I use other colors other than `primary` for color props?

EDIT:

This is how I create my color in theme:

```
    const theme = useMemo(
      () =>
        createMuiTheme({
          palette: {
            primary: {
              main: '#4297FF',
              mainGradient: "linear-gradient(-45deg,rgba(0, 101, 251, 1) 0%,rgba(0, 185, 255, 0.9251050762101716) 100%)",
            },
```

Here is the error I'm getting from my console.

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of value `linear-gradient(-45deg,rgba(0, 101, 251, 1) 0%,rgba(0, 185, 255, 0.9251050762101716) 100%)` supplied to `ForwardRef(TabIndicator)`, expected one of ["primary","secondary"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`indicatorColor` only accepts `'primary'` and `'secondary'` values, which sets the `background-color` to [`theme.palette.primary.main`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/661e595db02628a247bb8e529fb98aa92c0bb3b2/packages/material-ui/src/Tabs/TabIndicator.js#L15-L20) and `theme.palette.secondary.main` respectively.

You can see the full `TabIndicator` API [here](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#main-content).

To answer your question, you can add a custom style object directly to `TabIndicatorProps.style` like this:

```js
<Tabs
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    style: {
      height: 5,
      background:
        "linear-gradient(-45deg,rgba(0, 101, 251, 1) 0%,rgba(0, 185, 255, 0.9251050762101716) 100%)"
    }
  }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67010534/how-to-use-theme-colors-for-color-prop-used-in-materialui-components]